# Enable Shibboleth for Single SSL Virtual host on server with many vhosts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, virtualhost, shibboleth

We have a RHEL 5.5 server in production with a few NameBasedVirtual hosts listening on port 80.

We have also have two (possibly mis-configured) SSL virtual hosts which use different Sockets as required by the Apache & the SSL protocol:

- https://redcap-test.xyz.org
- https://jira.xyz.org

I am attempting to shibbolize only https://redcap-test.xyz.org.

After installing shibboleth 2.0 and configuring for a test identity provider, Shibboleth appears to be working on https://redcap.xyz.org.

Unfortunately, when i hit https://jira.xyz.org it also attempts to use shibboleth and throws an error.

Please note that jira.xyz.org and redcap-test.xyz.org worked fine using this configuration until I installed shibboleth.

**Is there some obvious place to enable or disable shibboleth on a per vhost basis?**

**Does anyone see any glaring mistakes in my virtual hosts, available here:**

- http://pastebin.com/M8175j51

**Or my shibboleth configuration:**

- http://pastebin.com/PwwTp7Xw

EDIT 1: I'm thinking maybe I can specify whether to use Shibboleth or not using the AuthType derivative...still looking for documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the apache configuration you've posted, it appears that you've ended up with shibboleth enabled globally rather than within the virtual host you want it to work in. I say "appears", since neither [AuthType nor Require](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApacheConfig#NativeSPApacheConfig-EnablingtheModuleforAuthentication) appear in the file you've posted, which implies to me that the authorization is set up globally under mods-enabled/shib.conf (or something similar).  You'll need to move the authorization bits from that file to the `<VirtualHost>` directive you want Shibboleth enabled on (or a `<Location>` or `<Directory>` directive within that vhost).

Comment: Yes...this. This makes sense. This is why I never ask questions on serverfault; It always ends up being something simple & makes me feel defeated. Irregardless - Thank you for solving

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a certificate that is issued for both domains using `subjectAltName`. See also: http://wiki.cacert.org/VhostTaskForce

Comment: This seems to apply to "Name Based Virtual Hosts" which is not what I am attempting to achieve. Both SSL Virtual hosts have their own socket (IP+Port) and function correctly when shibboleth is not installed. My problem is that when shibboleth is installed it's attempting to function on all SSL hosts and I need it only on 1 of the 2.